# How to implement independent cells in JavaFX?

Tags: java, javafx

I am trying to implement something similar to the choice of seats in a Theatre, Cinema, etc and their disponibility.

With this code:

```
int[] rowsColumns = getRowsNColumns(); // [0] = rows : [1] = columns
TableColumn [] tableColumns = new TableColumn[rowsColumns[1]];
Callback<TableColumn, TableCell> cellFactory =
        new Callback<TableColumn, TableCell>() {
            @Override
            public TableCell call(TableColumn p) {
                TableCell<MyObject,Boolean> cell = new DisponibilityCell();
                cell.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, new EventHandler());
                 return cell;
            }
        };
 for (int i = 0; i < rowsColumns[1]; i++) {
    tableColumns[i] = new TableColumn<MyObject, Boolean>(String.valueOf(i+1));
    tableColumns[i].setPrefWidth((table.getPrefWidth()-15)/rowsColumns[1]);
    tableColumns[i].setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<MyObject, Boolean>("disponibility"));
    tableColumns[i].setCellFactory(cellFactory);
    tableColumns[i].setSortable(false);
}
table.getColumns().addAll(tableColumns);
List<MyObject> list = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < rowsColumns[0]; i++) {
    list.add(new MyObject(i,true));
}
table.getItems().addAll(list);
table.getSelectionModel().setCellSelectionEnabled(true);
```

I am able to get this, which is quite what I want visually (without styles).
[image: Example image]

The problem is that it actually is generating the rows for the first column, and the other is just a copy of the values.

I think I understand this in theory, but do not know how to actually solve. If I understand correctly, it is considering an object for each row, and displaying the object property (`disponibility`) in all columns as all of them use the same get.

I want that each object is represented by a cell, not a row.
All cells from all rows get the same property, the `disponibility` of the seat, however each cell should be an independent object.

Comment: I think a GridView is more likely to be your choice of JavaFX Control, it is part of ControlsFX: http://controlsfx.bitbucket.org/org/controlsfx/control/GridView.html

Comment: I thought that might have a better way to do it, but as it should be simple I started with a normal TableView. Thank you, I will take a look soon.

Answer (score 1):

A working solution with a `TableView` could be this:

First of all we need to hold in `MyObject` the information for a each and every column of a given row. For that we use an `ObservableList` with all the boolean properties for the columns:

```
class MyObject {

    public MyObject(int tam, boolean disponibility){
        cols = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        IntStream.range(0, tam).boxed()
             .forEach(i->cols.add(new SimpleBooleanProperty(disponibility)));
    }

    private final ObservableList<BooleanProperty> cols;

    public void setColDisponibility(int col, boolean disponibility){
        cols.get(col).set(disponibility);
    }

    public boolean getColDisponibility(int col){
        return cols.get(col).get();
    }

    public BooleanProperty colDisponibilityProperty(int col){
        return cols.get(col);
    }
}
```

Now we will define our custom cell `DisponibilityCell`, based on a `CheckBox` for simplicity. A listener on this box will helps us keep in sync our model, by calling `setColDisponibility()`.

```
class DisponibilityCell extends TableCell<MyObject, Boolean> {
    private final CheckBox box = new CheckBox();

    public DisponibilityCell(int col){
        box.setOnAction(e -> {
            getTableView().getItems().get(getIndex()).setColDisponibility(col, box.isSelected());
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void updateItem(Boolean item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);

        if(item!=null && !empty){
            box.setSelected(item);
            setGraphic(box);
        }
        else {
            setText(null);
            setGraphic(null);
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, we can create the table. First, we provide all the data, setting to true every cell. Then we create the columns. For every column, we set its `id` to keep track of the number of column. We provide the cell value factory based on `colDisponibilityProperty(int col)` property, and the cell factory, based on a `DisponibilityCell`.

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

    TableView<MyObject> table = new TableView<>();
    table.setPrefSize(800, 600);

    int[] rowsColumns = new int[]{10,20}; // [0] = rows : [1] = columns
    ObservableList<MyObject> list = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    for (int i = 0; i < rowsColumns[0]; i++) {
        list.add(new MyObject(rowsColumns[1],true));
    }

    List<TableColumn<MyObject,Boolean>> tableColumns = new ArrayList<>(rowsColumns[1]);
    IntStream.range(0, rowsColumns[1]).boxed().forEach(i-> {
        TableColumn<MyObject,Boolean> tableColumn = new TableColumn<>(String.valueOf(i+1));
        tableColumn.setId(String.valueOf(i));
        tableColumn.setPrefWidth((table.getPrefWidth()-15)/rowsColumns[1]);
        tableColumn.setCellValueFactory(param -> {
            int col=Integer.parseInt(param.getTableColumn().getId());
            return param.getValue().colDisponibilityProperty(col);
        });
        tableColumn.setCellFactory(param -> 
             new DisponibilityCell(Integer.parseInt(param.getId())));
        tableColumn.setSortable(false);
        tableColumns.add(tableColumn);
    });
    table.getColumns().addAll(tableColumns);

    table.getItems().addAll(list);
    table.getSelectionModel().setCellSelectionEnabled(true);
    table.setEditable(true);

    Scene scene = new Scene(table, 800, 600);

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();

}
```

Note that you can access to your updated model at any time. For instance, you can print it based on some button click:

```
button.setOnMouseClicked(e->{
        table.getItems().forEach(r->{
            IntStream.range(0, rowsColumns[1]).boxed()
                    .forEach(i->System.out.print(" "+(r.getColDisponibility(i)?1:0)));
            System.out.println("");
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I would not use a TableView, it would enforce the seat layout to a strict row/column layout. Seats in Theaters or other locations are mostly different to that. So I would build an own layout of my seats from a theater specification, e.g.:

```
public class Seats extends Application {
    String theater1 = "20x__16x\n.20x__16x\n__18x__14x\n.20x__16x\n20x__16x\n.20x__16x\n20x__16x\n";
    String theater2 = "11x_10x_11x\n11x_10x_11x\n11x_10x_11x\n\n11x_10x_11x\n11x_10x_11x\n11x_10x_11x\n";

    static class Seat extends Group {
        Color freeColor = Color.rgb(30, 250, 40);
        Color reservedColor = Color.rgb(170, 40,  40);

        BooleanProperty iamReserved = new SimpleBooleanProperty(false);
        int myNo;
        public Seat(int no) {
            myNo = no;
            Circle pillow = new Circle(12);
            pillow.setFill(freeColor);
            pillow.setStrokeWidth(1);
            pillow.setStroke(Color.rgb(30, 40, 40));
            getChildren().add(pillow);

            Text lable = new Text(""+no);
            lable.setFont(lable.getFont().font(7));
            lable.setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER);
            lable.setTextOrigin(VPos.CENTER);
            lable.setLayoutX(-lable.getLayoutBounds().getWidth()/2);
            getChildren().add(lable);

            iamReserved.addListener((e, o, n) -> {
                pillow.setFill(n ? reservedColor : freeColor);
            });
            setOnMouseClicked(m -> {
                iamReserved.set(!iamReserved.get());
            });
        }

        static double width() { return 26; }
        static double height() { return 36; }
    }
    Pane theater1(Pane pane, String theater) {
        double x = 20;
        double y = 40;
        int no = 1;
        for (String row : theater.split("\n")) {
            int count = 0;
            for (int c : row.toCharArray()) {
                switch (c) {
                    case 'x': 
                        while (count-- > 0) {
                            Seat seat = new Seat(no++);
                            seat.setLayoutX(x); 
                            x+= Seat.width();
                            seat.setLayoutY(y);
                            pane.getChildren().add(seat);
                        }
                        count = 0;
                        break;
                    case '0': case '1': case '2': case '3': case '4': case '5': case'6': case '7': case '8': case '9':
                        count = 10*count + (c-'0');
                        break;
                    case '_':
                        x+= Seat.width();
                        break;
                    case '.':
                        x+= Seat.width()/2;
                        break;
                    default: System.out.println("Unknown char: '"+(char)c+"'");
                }
            }
            y += Seat.height();
            count = 0;
            x = 20;
        }
        return pane;
    }

    LinkedList<Node> myPages = new LinkedList<Node>();
    void addTab(String label, Region node) {
        myPages.add(node);
        node.setBackground(new Background(new BackgroundFill(Color.rgb(200, 170, 200), new CornerRadii(0), new Insets(0))));
    }


    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {        
        primaryStage.setTitle("Background of Panes");

        BorderPane border = new BorderPane();
        Pagination pages = new Pagination();
        Scene scene = new Scene(border,900,400,Color.WHITE);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);      

        addTab("1", theater1(new Pane(), theater1));
        addTab("2", theater1(new Pane(), theater2));

        pages.setPageCount(myPages.size());
        pages.setPageFactory(no -> myPages.get(no));

        border.setCenter(pages);

        primaryStage.show();   
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) { launch(args); }
}
```

resulting in free layouts like:

[image: theater1]

and

[image: theater2]

Comment: I agree with you, that would be a better solution. But can you add the imports you used? I am having some import conflicts here.

Comment: Actually, no more import problem, I was using jdk1.7 that's why. But it's actually outputting a blank pane only.

Comment: resize it, the it shows... had a problem with the Pagination init.

Comment: Had to add a Pane arround the Pagination to show also initially... done