# Restrict MouseEvent and Deselect Buttons @ JavaFX

Tags: button, javafx, mouseevent

Our project is to make a flight booking system where I have this 2D Array of seats represented as buttons – I am working with JavaFX.

I am not quite sure how to *restrict* the number of clicks (amount of tickets) when you book tickets for a customer. In addition I would also like to deselect seats (misclick – change booking – etc.) when using the system.

Anyone with some clever suggestions on what methods/Docs I should look at?

Comment: Try to use `ToggleButton` as a seat. You can style it with css to look like as seat later.

Comment: You might consider something like this discussed for Theater-Seats: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27110468/how-to-implement-independent-cells-in-javafx/27113623#27113623