# Processing a charArray - what happens here?

Tags: java, arrays

While reading through some questions here and trying to understanding the code I came about this interesting question and a for me very interesting solution by Jens-Peter Haack. See here: [How to implement independent cells in JavaFX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27110468/how-to-implement-independent-cells-in-javafx/27113623#27113623) - however don't understand some lines of code. Can someone please explain in detail what happens here:

```
case '0':
case '1':
case '2':
case '3':
case '4':
case '5':
case '6':
case '7':
case '8':
case '9':
    count = 10 * count + (c - '0');
```

Unfortuneatly I haven't found a way to ask the author directly.

Comment: you can try to run this piece of code manually

Comment: whats c and whats count? show more code plz.

Comment: @AndrewTobilko - i did - but i don't understand whats happening here and how the magic works. MRK187 - please check the link included for full source

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a part of `switch-case` statement. Seems that `switch(c)` is somewhere before this code. This means that if `c` is any character expressing the digit (from `'0'` to `'9'`), then update a `count`: multiply it by `10`, then add that digit. Subtracting `'0'` is necessary to convert the character (like `'1'`) to number `1`.

Comment: Thanks! Your last sentence brought me to this post: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4318300/3989910 and then i got the whole thing!