# JavaFX and addListener function

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2

As seen here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27113623/7326194 I have created a similar Theater.

I don't really know how to properly use addListener.. I'd like that a customer could only select one seat at time (one red circle at time), and not more than one, so I am trying to set the previous selected red Seat as free, if it was one (green color and boolean occupied = false), whenever the customer select a new Seat different by the red one, and set to red the new Seat.

Can you help me?

I would really appreciate your help.

---

```
class Seat extends Group {
    Color freeColor = Color.rgb(30, 250, 40);
    Color freeColorClasse = Color.rgb(255, 255, 0);
    Color reservedColor = Color.rgb(170, 40,  40);

    int contatoreBase = 0, contatorePC = 0;
    BooleanProperty iamReserved = new SimpleBooleanProperty(false);
    int myNo;

    public Seat(int no) {

        myNo = no;
        Circle pillow = new Circle(12);

        if ( no <= 64) {
            pillow.setFill(freeColorClasse);
        }
        else {
            pillow.setFill(freeColor);
        }

        pillow.setStrokeWidth(1);
        pillow.setStroke(Color.rgb(30, 40, 40));
        getChildren().add(pillow);

        Text lable = new Text(""+no);
        lable.setFont(Font.font(11));
        lable.setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER);
        lable.setTextOrigin(VPos.CENTER);
        lable.setLayoutX(-lable.getLayoutBounds().getWidth()/2);
        getChildren().add(lable);

        iamReserved.addListener((e, o, n) -> {
            pillow.setFill(n ? reservedColor : (no > 64 ? freeColor: freeColorClasse));
        });
        setOnMouseClicked(m -> {

            iamReserved.set(!iamReserved.get());          
        });
    }


}
Pane theater1(Pane pane, String theater) {
    double x = 20;
    double y = 40;
    int no = 1;


    for (String row : theater.split("\n")) {
        int count = 0;
        for (int c : row.toCharArray()) {
            switch (c) {
                case 'x': 
                    while (count-- > 0) {
                        Seat seat = new Seat(no++);
                        seat.setLayoutX(x); 
                        x+=26;
                        seat.setLayoutY(y);
                        pane.getChildren().add(seat);
                    }
                    count = 0;
                    break;
                case '0': case '1': case '2': case '3': case '4': case '5': case'6': case '7': case '8': case '9':
                    count = 10 * count + (c - '0');
                    break;
                case '_':
                    x+=26;
                    break;
                case '.':
                    x+=13;
                    break;
                default: System.out.println("Unknown char: '"+(char)c+"'");
            }
        }
        y+=36;
        x = 20;
    }
    return pane;
}
```

That's the code, only the part to create the Theater

Answer (score 0):

You could implement a `Skin` for `RadioButton`, since this `Control` already provides the functionality you're looking for. It just does not look the way you need want it. By using a `Skin` you can change this:

```
public class SeatRadioSkin extends SkinBase<RadioButton> {

    private final Circle circle;
    private final Label text;
    private final EventHandler<MouseEvent> downHandler = evt -> {
        if (evt.getButton() == MouseButton.PRIMARY) {
            RadioButton btn = getSkinnable();

            if (!btn.isFocused() && btn.isFocusTraversable()) {
                btn.requestFocus();
            }

            if (!btn.isArmed()) {
                btn.arm();
            }
        }
    };

    private final EventHandler<MouseEvent> upHandler = evt -> {
        if (evt.getButton() == MouseButton.PRIMARY) {
            RadioButton btn = getSkinnable();

            if (btn.isArmed()) {
                btn.disarm();
                btn.fire();
            }
        }
    };

    public SeatRadioSkin(RadioButton button) {
        super(button);
        circle = new Circle();
        circle.setManaged(false);
        circle.getStyleClass().setAll("seat");

        text = new Label();
        text.setManaged(false);
        text.textProperty().bind(button.textProperty());
        text.getStyleClass().setAll("text");

        getChildren().setAll(circle, text);
        button.getStyleClass().setAll("seat-radio-button");
        button.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED, downHandler);
        button.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_RELEASED, upHandler);
        // todo: more event handlers
    }

    @Override
    protected void layoutChildren(double contentX, double contentY, double contentWidth, double contentHeight) {
        circle.setRadius(Math.min(contentWidth, contentHeight) / 2);
        layoutInArea(circle, contentX, contentY, contentWidth, contentHeight, -1, HPos.CENTER, VPos.CENTER);
        text.resize(contentWidth, contentHeight);
        layoutInArea(text, contentX, contentY, contentWidth, contentHeight, -1, HPos.CENTER, VPos.CENTER);
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        text.textProperty().unbind();
        RadioButton btn = getSkinnable();

        btn.removeEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED, downHandler);
        btn.removeEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_RELEASED, upHandler);

        // todo: remove additional event handlers

        super.dispose();
    }

    private double prefSize(double widthOffset, double heightOffset) {
        RadioButton btn = getSkinnable();
        double w = Math.max(30, btn.getPrefWidth()) + widthOffset;
        double h = Math.max(30, btn.getPrefHeight()) + heightOffset;
        return Math.min(w, h);
    }

    @Override
    protected double computePrefHeight(double width, double topInset, double rightInset, double bottomInset, double leftInset) {
        return prefSize(leftInset + rightInset, topInset + bottomInset);
    }

    @Override
    protected double computePrefWidth(double height, double topInset, double rightInset, double bottomInset, double leftInset) {
        return prefSize(leftInset + rightInset, topInset + bottomInset);
    }

}
```

**CSS**

```css
.seat-radio-button .seat {
    -fx-fill: -seat-fill;
    -fx-stroke: black;
}

.seat-radio-button:disabled {
    -seat-fill-base: #444;
    -text-fill: white;
}

.seat-radio-button:focused .seat {
    -fx-effect: dropshadow(one-pass-box, -fx-focus-color, 10, 0, 0, 0);
}

.seat-radio-button .text {
    -fx-fill: -text-fill;
}

.seat-radio-button {
    -seat-fill-base: lime;
    -seat-fill: -seat-fill-base;
    -text-fill: black;
}

.seat-radio-button:armed {
    -seat-fill: ladder(#aaa, black 0%, -seat-fill-base 100%);
}

.seat-radio-button:selected {
    -seat-fill-base: red;
}
```

**Example use**

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    ToggleGroup group = new ToggleGroup();

    RadioButton btn = createSeat("100", 30, 30, group);
    RadioButton btn2 = createSeat("101", 30, 30, group);
    RadioButton btn3 = createSeat("102", 30, 30, group);

    btn2.setDisable(true);

    HBox root = new HBox(10, btn, btn2, btn3);
    root.setPadding(new Insets(10));

    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 200, 50);
    scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("style.css").toExternalForm());

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a very simple "selection model", simply by representing the selected seat as an `ObjectProperty<Seat>`. Add the usual get/set/property methods to the `Seat` class:

```
class Seat extends Group {
    private Color freeColor = Color.rgb(30, 250, 40);
    private Color freeColorClasse = Color.rgb(255, 255, 0);
    private Color reservedColor = Color.rgb(170, 40,  40);

    private int contatoreBase = 0, contatorePC = 0;
    private BooleanProperty iamReserved = new SimpleBooleanProperty(false);
    private int myNo;

    public BooleanProperty reservedProperty() {
        return iamReserved ;
    }

    public final boolean isReserved() {
        return reservedProperty().get();
    }

    public final void setReserved(boolean reserved) {
        reservedProperty().set(reserved);
    }

    // existing code omitted...

}
```

Now you can do:

```
private final ObjectProperty<Seat> reservedSeat = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();

Pane theater1(Pane pane, String theater) {
    double x = 20;
    double y = 40;
    int no = 1;


    for (String row : theater.split("\n")) {
        int count = 0;
        for (int c : row.toCharArray()) {
            switch (c) {
                case 'x': 
                    while (count-- > 0) {
                        Seat seat = new Seat(no++);
                        seat.setLayoutX(x); 
                        x+=26;
                        seat.setLayoutY(y);
                        pane.getChildren().add(seat);

                        seat.reservedProperty().addListener((obs, wasReserved, isNowReserved) -> {
                            if (isNowReserved) {
                                if (reservedSeat.get() != null) {
                                    reservedSeat.get().setReserved(false);
                                }
                                reservedSeat.set(seat);
                            } else {
                                reservedSeat.set(null);
                            }
                        });

                    }
                    count = 0;
                    break;
                case '0': case '1': case '2': case '3': case '4': case '5': case'6': case '7': case '8': case '9':
                    count = 10 * count + (c - '0');
                    break;
                case '_':
                    x+=26;
                    break;
                case '.':
                    x+=13;
                    break;
                default: System.out.println("Unknown char: '"+(char)c+"'");
            }
        }
        y+=36;
        x = 20;
    }
    return pane;
}
```

Comment: Perfect James_D, that's exactly what I was looking for! I am studying right now JavaFX, and I have never heard about ObjectProperty.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your help, now I am tryng to add a SQL database to keep reserved booked seats.

Comment: Hi James_D, your solution were elegant and simple. Thanks a lot. I am having some issues with static and final variables. My javaFX app allows a use to book a seat. How can I save in a variable the selected seat(I have to check if no one is selected and if the selected one is already busy)?

Comment: I open a post [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42330027/javafx-issues-with-static-and-dynamic-code?)    Can you help me to improve this new functionality to your code please?

Comment: @Condo I saw that post and have no clue what you are asking.

Comment: I think you're the only one who can help me.. As you have seen from the picture [here] (http://imgur.com/a/UFvRs) red seats are full, free green, and the orange one  it is the place that a user has selected in my application. I need a int to update my database. That int has to be equal to the myno variable, so I can store in the selected database That seat is busy right now.

I only need and "int" to keep the number of the orange seat, even if the user dinamically change it, but I can not do that. Can you help me? That only problem I have to resolve to finish my app ...Thanks a lot @James_D